# Does a graphical driver chip exist for this project?

Tags: lcd

I need some expert advice. I'm using an Arduino Leonardo, which I have got working with a Nokia 3310 monochrome screen. I wrote some code to draw any graphics to the screen.

What I want to know is, can I buy a chip from somewhere that will offload most of the CPU usage (for graphics from the Leonardo) that draws numbers and letters to the screen and basic graphics (different types of polygons and lines)? So I'm looking for a chip designed to do the graphical work and a data sheet reference for the chip.

Comment: Just get a second arduino. e.g. a pro-mini.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea if there is a chip or not, but I doubt it.

But then, why do you need one?

You already know how to communicate with the screen, so why not off-load those functions on to another Arduino (make your own small ATMega328P based board to do it) and then communicate with that through whatever means you like from your Leonardo?

You don't *need* a dedicated chip to do what you can quite easily program an Arduino to do.